# Socket.io 4.x - How do I fetch users as username lists?

Tags: sockets, websocket, socket.io

First, the client enters the room name and user name. And I'm sending them to the server.

**Client**

```
socket.on('connect', () => {
    socket.emit("join", { roomID: roomID, name: name });
})
```

Then I take it on the server and put it in the room.

**Server** console.log(room) returns {roomID: "1", name: "user"}, so it's good

```
io.on('connection', socket => {
            socket.broadcast.emit('a user connected')
            socket.on('join', (room) => {
                console.log(room);
                socket.join(room.roomID);
            });
        })
```

Now I need to send the list of users in this room back to the client.

However

1. How do I use the username when doing socket.join?
2. How do I send the users in this room to the client as a list? (I need usernames)

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have kept the list of users somewhere, you can use a call back

##### Client

```
socket.on('connect', () => {
    socket.emit("join", { roomID: roomID, name: name }, (data) => {
          //This is the function that's called below using callback.
    });
})
```

##### SERVER

```
socket.on('join', (room, callback) => {
   console.log(room);
   socket.join(room.roomID);
   callback(/* array of users here */)
});
```